# Systematic way to find what's corrupt in Chrome profile on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

Something happened to my Chrome profile where it now takes almost a minute for Chrome to open.  If I rename my Default folder in AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data which contains my profile, it opens instantly and creates a fresh Default.

Is there a fast/automated way to discover the bad folder/file?  There's about a thousand files inside a thousand folders under Default, so I'm hoping to avoid temporarily renaming each file/folder one by one then relaunching Chrome to see which one it is.